# Position independent code and Shared Object

Tags: compiler-construction, shared-libraries, compiler-optimization, code-sharing

Anyone please explain what Position independent code and Shared Object meant actually. Whether the object code created after compiling is Position independent.

It would be helpful if somebody explain about how the access to local/external variables are handled in a position independent code.

Also looking for some real-life dynamic linking/loading examples/situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One good general [explanation](http://www.greyhat.ch/lab/downloads/pic.html) with lots of examples.

Comment: link broken. Can you provide an current version of it ?

Answer (score 2):

The link provided by Employed Russian is a good one. However, [here's another article](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/03/position-independent-code-pic-in-shared-libraries/) on this topic that you may find useful. It assumes less knowledge and perhaps can be easier to understand for a beginner.

Comment: Helluva link. Thanks buddy!